# SQL multiple proximity search

Tags: sql, ms-access, proximity

I'm new to SQL in Access database. I am looking to mine text in rows based on multiple proximity searches. In simple boolean terms I am looking for:

```
(term1 or term2) Near5 (term 3 or term 4)
```

switching this to SQL proves to be a bit challenging. Using near:

```
CONTAINS('NEAR((term1,term2),5) OR NEAR((term3,term4),5, TRUE)')
```

but this isn't right. suggestions?

Comment: Can you add example data and expected output?

Comment: Does MsAccess even support `Near`?  I dont think it does.